How Can I Tunnel WireGuard on Rooted Android 14 Through v2rayNG?
I’m trying to tunnel WireGuard on my rooted Android 14 device through v2rayNG. Since the WireGuard client doesn’t support this by default, is there any way to achieve this, perhaps by using iptables or another method?
Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
